# Using if elif fi in shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell

I'm not sure how to do an `if` with multiple tests in shell. I'm having trouble writing this script:

```
echo "You have provided the following arguments $arg1 $arg2 $arg3"
if [ "$arg1" = "$arg2" && "$arg1" != "$arg3" ]
then
    echo "Two of the provided args are equal."
    exit 3
elif [ $arg1 = $arg2 && $arg1 = $arg3 ]
then
    echo "All of the specified args are equal"
    exit 0
else
    echo "All of the specified args are different"
    exit 4
fi
```

The problem is I get this error every time:

> ./compare.sh: [: missing `]' command not found

Comment: Quite a few commentators have suggested you use [[ rather than [ but that makes your script bash-specific.  You'll have fewer maintenance and portability issues if you can stick to plain old Bourne shell (sh) syntax.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`sh` is interpreting the `&&` as a shell operator. Change it to `-a`, that’s `[`’s conjunction operator:

```
[ "$arg1" = "$arg2" -a "$arg1" != "$arg3" ]
```

Also, you should always quote the variables, because `[` gets confused when you leave off arguments.

Answer (score 47):

Josh Lee's answer works, but you can use the "&&" operator for better readability like this:

```
echo "You have provided the following arguments $arg1 $arg2 $arg3"
if [ "$arg1" = "$arg2" ] && [ "$arg1" != "$arg3" ]
then 
    echo "Two of the provided args are equal."
    exit 3
elif [ $arg1 = $arg2 ] && [ $arg1 = $arg3 ]
then
    echo "All of the specified args are equal"
    exit 0
else
    echo "All of the specified args are different"
    exit 4 
fi
```

Answer (score 9):

I have a sample from your code. Try this:

```
echo "*Select Option:*"
echo "1 - script1"
echo "2 - script2"
echo "3 - script3 "
read option
echo "You have selected" $option"."
if [ $option="1" ]
then
    echo "1"
elif [ $option="2" ]
then
    echo "2"
    exit 0
elif [ $option="3" ]
then
    echo "3"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Please try again from given options only."
fi
```

This should work. :)

Comment: Gawd this looks quirky to me. Why no `then` after `else`?
It may actually not be quirky, but that's how it looks, compared to C.

Comment: space is required after $option and before = to run it fine, else every time 1

Answer (score 8):

Use double brackets...

`if [[ expression ]]`

Comment: To note, this is a solution because the `[[` construct is built into the shell while `[` is another name for the `test` command and hence is subject to its syntax -- see `man test`

Comment: Technically, `[` is a shell builtin, but `[[` is a shell keyword. That’s the difference.

Comment: So see the results of the bash commands `type [`, `type [[`, `help [` and `help [[`.

Comment: @JoshLee no, there is a file called `/usr/bin/[`

Answer (score 5):

Change `[` to `[[`, and `]` to `]]`.

Comment: Better yet, change '[' to 'test'

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me,

```
 # cat checking.sh
 #!/bin/bash
 echo "You have provided the following arguments $arg1 $arg2 $arg3"
 if [ "$arg1" = "$arg2" ] && [ "$arg1" != "$arg3" ]
 then
     echo "Two of the provided args are equal."
     exit 3
 elif [ $arg1 == $arg2 ] && [ $arg1 = $arg3 ]
 then
     echo "All of the specified args are equal"
     exit 0
 else
     echo "All of the specified args are different"
     exit 4
 fi

 # ./checking.sh
 You have provided the following arguments
 All of the specified args are equal
```

You can add `set -x` in script to troubleshoot the errors.