# Shell - check if a git tag exists in an if/else statement

Tags: git, bash, shell

I am creating a deploy script for a zend application. The script is almost done only I want to verify that a tag exists within the repo to force tags on the team. Currently I have the following code:

```
# First update the repo to make sure all the tags are in
cd /git/repo/path
git pull

# Check if the tag exists in the rev-list. 
# If it exists output should be zero, 
# else an error will be shown which will go to the else statement.
if [ -z "'cd /git/repo/path && git rev-list $1..'" ]; then
    
    echo "gogo"

else

    echo "No or no correct GIT tag found"    
    exit

fi
```

Looking forward to your feedback!

## Update

When I execute the following in the command line:

```
cd /git/repo/path && git rev-list v1.4..
```

I get **NO** output, which is good. Though when I execute:

```
cd /git/repo/path && git rev-list **BLA**..
```

I get an **error**, which again is good:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'BLA..': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

The -z in the statement says, if sting is empty then... In other words, it works fine via command line. Though when I use the same command in a shell script inside a statement it does not seem to work.

```
[ -z "'cd /git/repo/path && git rev-list $1..'" ]
```

This method is inspired by [Validate if commit exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127967/validate-if-commit-exists)

## Update 2

I found the problem:

See [Using if elif fi in shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359270/using-if-elif-fi-in-shell-scripts) >

> sh is interpreting the && as a shell operator. Change it to -a, that’s
> [’s conjunction operator:
>
> [ "$arg1" = "$arg2" -a "$arg1" != "$arg3" ] Also, you should always
> quote the variables, because [ gets confused when you leave off
> arguments.

in other words, I changed the `&&` to `;` and simplified the condition. Now it works beautiful.

```
if cd /path/to/repo ; git rev-list $1.. >/dev/null

then

    echo "gogo"

else
    echo "WRONG"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: is the `$sha` variable defined elsewhere?

Comment: also note that `git pull` does a merge after updating the references, you'd want to use `git fetch` instead

Comment: and see [Bash/Shell Script Function to Verify Git Tag or Commit Exists and Has Been Pushed to Remote Repository](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3418674)

Comment: Oke let me explain a bit more, see the update in the description.

Comment: I would suggest that `git rev-parse --verify refs/tags/${tagname}` is probably the better way to do this... (It at least seems to be the primary `git` does this internally...).

Comment: "'cd /git/repo/path && git rev-list $1..'" isn't an empty string - it contains 'cd /git/repo/path && git rev-list $1..' - perhaps you meant to execute the command rather than just putting it as text?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You could use `git rev-parse` instead:

```
if GIT_DIR=/path/to/repo/.git git rev-parse $1 >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "Found tag"
else
    echo "Tag not found"
fi
```

`git rev-list` invokes graph walking, where `git rev-parse` would avoid it.  The above has some issues with possibly looking up an object instead of a tag.  You can avoid that by using `^{tag}` following the tag name, but this only works for annotated tags and not lightweight tags:

```
if GIT_DIR=/path/to/repo/.git git rev-parse "$1^{tag}" >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "Found tag"
else
    echo "Tag not found"
fi
```

@Lassi also points out that if your tag name begins with a `-`, then it might get interpreted as an option instead.  You can avoid that issue by looking for `refs/tags/$1` instead.  So in summary, with the `rev-parse` version, you can look for `refs/tags/$1` to get both lightweight and annotated tags, and you can append a `^{tag}` to the end to enforce an annotated tag (`refs/tags/$1^{tag}`).

Also, as mentioned before by @forvaidya, you could simply list the tags and grep for the one you want:

```
if GIT_DIR=/path/to/repo/.git git show-ref --tags | egrep -q "refs/tags/$1$"
then
    echo "Found tag"
else
    echo "Tag not found"
fi
```

You can also use `git tag --list` instead of `git show-ref --tags`:

```
if GIT_DIR=/path/to/repo/.git git tag --list | egrep -q "^$1$"
then
    echo "Found tag"
else
    echo "Tag not found"
fi
```

If you know the tag though, I think it's best just to just look it up via `rev-parse`.  One thing I don't like about the `egrep` version is that it's possible you could have characters that could get interpreted as regex sequences and either cause a false positive or false negative.  The `rev-parse` version is superior in that sense, and in that it doesn't look at the whole list of tags.

Another option is to use the pattern feature of `git show-ref`:

```
if GIT_DIR=/path/to/repo/.git git show-ref --tags "refs/tags/$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "Found tag"
else
    echo "Tag not found"
fi
```

This avoids the extra `egrep` invocation and is a bit more direct.

Comment: Yes, defining the GIT_DIR is a good way! I think they both work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The `rev-parse` option will match a Git "long" tag (generated by `git describe`), but the second option matches only real tags. Thanks! I don't see any advantage in using `git show-ref --tags` over `git tag --list`, though. Does it matter?

Comment: @big_m it does not matter.  You just need to make sure to match it correctly... so use something like `egrep -q "^$1$"` to match sure you match the entire entry.

Comment: @big_m I updated the answer with an extra block showing how you can use the `rev-parse` version to only look for a tag.

Comment: Thanks for `^{tag}` suffix tip, @jszakmeister! Could have sworn I tried that, but apparently not (or not correctly anyway). I just tried it again and it works, just as you say.

Comment: `show-ref` can use a pattern as well, so why not use `git show-ref --tags "$1"` rather than `git show-ref --tags | egrep -q "refs/tags/$1$"`

Comment: @OscarScholten The default behavior is to match starting at the back of the full ref.  Let's assume that `$1` was "foo".  If you had the tags `foo` and `bar/foo`, `git show-ref --tags "foo"` would show both of them.  OTOH, using `git show-ref --tags "refs/tags/$1"` would work, and is a nicer solution.

Answer (score 125):

Why so complicated? Here’s a dead-simple solution (based on [cad106uk’s approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36772966/3908235) further down the page):

```
version=1.2.3

if [ $(git tag -l "$version") ]; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

It is not necessary to compare the output of `git tag -l` with the version number, because the output will be empty if the version is not found. Therefore it’s sufficient to test if there’s any output at all.

Note: The quotes around `$version` are important to avoid false positives. Because if `$version` is empty for some reason, `git tag -l` would just list *all* tags, and the condition would always be true.

Answer (score 21):

Here's the **rev-parse** version developed further:

```
tag=whatever
if git rev-parse -q --verify "refs/tags/$tag" >/dev/null; then
    echo "found"
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

It appears to be robust:

- Checks **only for a tag**, not a branch or a commit hash, etc.
- Weird tag name input doesn't cause weird behavior:

  - Tag names starting with "-" are not mistaken for command line options
  - Tag names containing slashes or dots are not special
  - Tag names containing whitespace are not special
  - Blank tag name isn't special

Comment: Unfortunately, if the $tag string ends with "-q" and a string of 7 or more hex digits (such as in the generated "long" tags from `git describe`), this will match on the commit hash, even if there's no such tag. The grep option with `git tag --list` or `git show-ref --tags` is the only option I've found that avoids this.

Answer (score 10):

Very Simple Version(use git ls-remote)

```
TAG_NAME=$1
git ls-remote --exit-code --tags origin $TAG_NAME || echo 'not found'
```

Answer (score 7):

The solution I quite like which I think is using a more modern version of git (git version 2.7.4)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /to/repo/base;
tagName="Whatever";

if [[ `git tag -l $tagName` == $tagName ]]; then
    echo "yes";
else
    echo "no";
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're in the project root directory...

```
# Filename: check-for-tag
# Usage:    check-for-tag <TAG_NAME>
# Example:  check-for-tag ticket-123-fix-this-bug
TAG_NAME=$1
git ls-remote --tags 2>/dev/null | grep $TAG_NAME 1>/dev/null
if [ "$?" == 0 ]; then 
   echo "Git tag $TAG_NAME exists."
else  
   echo "Git tag $TAG_NAME does not exist."
fi
```

Comment: You can run `git ls-remote --tags 2>/dev/null | grep "refs/tags/$TAG_NAME$" 1>/dev/null` if you want to know if the exact tag exists.

Answer (score 1):

I use this method to tell if a tag exists for the current revision, to avoid tagging twice.

```
git_rev_id=$(git -C $REPO_FOLDER rev-parse HEAD)
git_tags=$(git tag)

for git_tag in $git_tags; do
    git_temp_tag=$(git cat-file tag $git_tag | grep $git_rev_id);
    if [ -z "$git_temp_tag" ]
    then
        false; #do nothing
    else
        git_tag_exists=$git_tag
    fi
done

if [ -z "$git_tag_exists" ]
then
  echo "need to make a tag"
else
  echo "Found tag: $git_tag_exits"
fi
```