# How to check if tag exists in if/else

Tags: git, bash, if-statement

How can I check if a tag exists in my GIT repo.
I get as input some tagname and I have to check if it's a valid tag with a `if else statement.`
TAG="tagname"

I tried:

```
if [ git rev-parse ${TAG} >/dev/null 2>&1 ]; then
  echo "tag exists";
else
  echo "tag does not exist";
```

But it didn't work

Comment: Use the exit status returned from the command and so run the command and then use the if statement on $? to find the tag.

Comment: @RamanSailopal is this possible to do in one if statement? (nothing above the if)

Comment: You are missing a `fi` at the end. (Unrelated: `[[` is to be preferred over `[`.)

Comment: @RamanSailopal There is no reason to run the command and use the exit status as you suggested. The `if [[ ....]` is perfectly fine.

Comment: It won't work unless the whole git statement is placed in $() Using $? is an alternate way of doing it but if the poster cannot insert anything above the if statement then using $(git rev-parse ${TAG} >/dev/null 2>&1) is the best way to go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shell - check if a git tag exists in an if/else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790123/shell-check-if-a-git-tag-exists-in-an-if-else-statement)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `if` with a command without `test` (or it synonym `[`) and the `if` command will treat the exit status as the conditional.  If it exits with "success" (i.e., `0`) then it's true, otherwise it's false:

```
if git rev-parse "$TAG" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "tag exists";
else
  echo "tag does not exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 12):

## Easier and cleaner solution

```sh
if git show-ref --tags tag1 --quiet; then
  echo "tag exists"
else 
  echo "tag doesn't exist or error in command"
fi
```

`git show-ref` exits with exit-code 1 if a tag isn't found (see [Git code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b8367d1f012ceb86ab48c9024a1bac111bb52dde/builtin/show-ref.c#L232-L236), didn't find doc for it).
There are other if-constructs to check for exit-codes, though (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26675681/1168315)).

## Restrict `git rev-parse` to only tags

`git rev-parse --tags=$TAG` only finds tags (the `=` is necessary), whereas `git rev-parse $REF` finds all kind of [revisions](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) (i.e. also branches and SHAs).

Comment: `git rev-parse --tags=$TAG` doesn't work for me on either Windows or Linux, but `git rev-parse $REF` does, however, as you say it also finds branches, not just tags.

Comment: @CJDennis Strange. I've tested it on MacOS with `git` from Homebrew (version `2.28.0`) only, though. Perhaps the `--verify` parameter gives some insight?

Answer (score 0):

I found only

```
git rev-parse "refs/tags/$TAG" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

gives a reliable indication of whether `$TAG` is an existing tag.