# Check if a github tag exists in a repo within a github action

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to check if a specific tag exists in a repository. Here is a simplified version of what I have tried so far.

Attempt 1:

```
name: Check for Tag

on: push

jobs:
  check-tag:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check for Tag
        run: |
          TAG="0.1"
          if git show-ref --tags --verify --quiet "refs/tags/${TAG}"; then
            echo "Tag ${TAG} exists"
          else
            echo "Tag ${TAG} does not exist"
          fi
```

Output: Tag 0.1 does not exist

However if i execute the following command on CLI, the tag exists
[image]

`git show-ref --tags --verify` returns an exit code of `0` if the tag has been found.

Attempt 2:

```
name: Check for Tag

on: push

jobs:
  check-tag:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Check for Tag
        run: |
          TAG="0.2"
          git show-ref --tags --verify --quiet "refs/tags/${TAG}" 
          exit_code=$?
          echo ${exit_code}
          if [[ $exit_code -eq 0 ]]; then
            echo "Tag ${TAG} exists"
          else
            echo "Tag ${TAG} does not exist"
          fi
```

The workflow fails because `0.2` tag does not exist and returns 1 as exit code

Comment: With `actions/checkout`, use `fetch-depth: 0` to fetch the complete git history.

Comment: See your updated workflow [here](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJx9T0tOwzAQ3fsUTxFbkwp2RkigLrhAL+C649hQ7JAZ9yPg7jikhCwQK3vedybZVzJYB3Iv8HnAxnZK5WTQFw5KPectGwW4UaDFduMADCWxHlVlW5IUvbdCLOqbY6GeJxmgkX4LcpELDBQmNrBOYk7cugv9cLidFccowcwT4Elc0DvqK4zVTPxVNF/yI6r7GnwswjaPT/fN6vqmWWDRo4sCDvmoB/LQ471cnwMN0Z/r561EEjSV5Hbk2qv3GvTZ3EECpUUUQC5kNHUHTBrQKbLwso/2TP97dpkYKctkXnp9VF94eXYZ).

Comment: @Azeem Argh can't believe i missed that. Post the comment as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the complete git history to query that.

Use `fetch-depth: 0` with `actions/checkout`.

Here's your updated workflow:

```yaml
name: Check for Tag

on: push

jobs:
  check-tag:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
        
      - name: Check for Tag
        run: |
          TAG="0.2"
          if git show-ref --tags --verify --quiet "refs/tags/${TAG}"; then
            echo "Tag ${TAG} exists"
          else
            echo "Tag ${TAG} does not exist"
          fi
```

See https://github.com/actions/checkout for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the strategy outlined in [Shell - check if a git tag exists in an if/else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790123/shell-check-if-a-git-tag-exists-in-an-if-else-statement) to figure out whether the tag exists or not.

```yaml
name: Check for Tag

on: push

jobs:
  check-tag:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Check for Tag
        run: |
          TAG="0.1"
          if [ $(git tag -l "${TAG}") ]; then
            echo "Tag ${TAG} exists"
          else
            echo "Tag ${TAG} does not exist"
          fi
```

I tested this in my own github repository, you can see that in [this run](https://github.com/ethansocal/tag-checker/actions/runs/4879644042/jobs/8706403913), the tag was not found, but when I published tag 0.1, [this run](https://github.com/ethansocal/tag-checker/actions/runs/4879650662) shows that it is successful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is an action doing exactly what you need on the marketplace, namely [tag-exists-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/tag-exists-action). As of the repository, it looks maintained (as of today).

An example usage is

```
- uses: mukunku/tag-exists-action@v1.4.0
  id: checkTag
  with: 
    tag: '0.1'

- run: echo ${{ steps.checkTag.outputs.exists }}
```